# AM Charts initial view using zoomToDates

Tags: amcharts

Been stumped on this for a little bit.

I found some other help on zoomToIndexes, but I cant get the zoomToDates to work on my page.

Live page is
[b2 resource urq sales](http://b2resource.com/urqsales.php)

Im trying to  set the initial view to show from 2000 to current.. I want to slap some original sales data from early 80's in the graph, but dont want the graph to initially show the last 30+ years..

Any help would be MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

[`zoomToDates`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#zoomToDates) takes real JavaScript Date objects as parameters:

```
chart.zoomToDates(new Date(2005, 0, 1), new Date(2015, 11, 31));
```

You can use chart's [`rendered`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#rendered) event to "pre-zoom" on load as well:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // your chart config
  // ...
});

chart.addListener("rendered", function(event) {
  event.chart.zoomToDates(new Date(2005, 0, 1), new Date(2015, 11, 31));
});
```

Note, that months in Date() constructor parameter (second parameter) are zero-based. Meaning January is 0, February - 1, etc.

Comment: Hmmm, still having a tough time getting this to work!

Comment: What do you have so far? Your link does not seem to have any of the above code applied to it.

Comment: Correct.. I tried using the code you posted but couldnt really figure out where to place it, and thus having it work.

Comment: I suggest you contact amCharts support directly. Further discussion like this is out of StackOverflow format. You can refer to this thread when you contact amCharts. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use valueAxis property of chart object for zoomToValues. I hope this might help you.

```
 var chart= AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
      "type": "gantt",
      "theme": "black",
           ...
    });

    zoomChart();
    chart.addListener("dataUpdated", zoomChart);



 function zoomChart(event) {
   chart.valueAxis.zoomToValues(new Date(2017, 2, 10), new Date(2017,2,12));
  // or ==> event.chart.valueAxis.zoomToValues(new Date(2017, 2, 10), new Date(2017,2,12));
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart('chartdiv', {
  type: 'serial',
  ...
});

chart.addListener('dataUpdated', zoomChart);

zoomChart();

function zoomChart() {
  chart.zoomToDates(new Date(2018, 2, 26), new Date(2018, 2, 28));
}
```

Note: The months parameter in Date() constructor are zero-based. January is 0, February is 1 and etc.